# How to select a varying number of cells using range in excel vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, cell

I am trying to pull unique names from a list of names in my code.
This currently works:

```
Set myRng = Sheets("quoteData_1").Range("Q2:Q8314")
Set r = Sheets("quoteData_1").Range("Z2")
myRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=myRng, CopyToRange:=r, Unique:=True
```

Currently I can hard code the column of cells that I wish to filter through for this but I would like to to alter this code so that it works with any length of the column as I will never know the exact length that I need. Between research and some experince I thought this would work but it does not ('rowIdx' is found earlier as an integer value pertaining to be the value of the last row):

```
Set myRng = Sheets("quoteData_1").Range(Cells(2,17),Cells(rowIdx,17))
Set r = Sheets("quoteData_1").Range("Z2")
myRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=myRng, CopyToRange:=r, Unique:=True
```

The Error I encounter reads:
*Run-time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error*

So how am I able to use range with a varying number of cells and avoid using the name of the cell as in R5:R75?

Comment: `Set myRng = Sheets("quoteData_1").Range(Sheets("quoteData_1".Cells(2,17),Sheets("quoteData_1".Cells(rowIdx,17))`

Comment: Or `With Sheets("quoteData_1")`, `Set myRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 17), .Cells(rowIdx, 17))`, `End With`.